# specify non-printing keys as input to shell command

Tags: command-line, keyboard, scripts, input, ncurses

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server 64

I have a shell script that runs in unattended mode.

The script executes a command that displays a curses/ncurses UI which normally expects the user to navigate a menu via keyboard.

To emulate user-navigation, I need to input a sequence of keys :

```
echo -e "{up-arrow} {space-bar} {enter-key}" | mycommand
```

A literal space `" "` might work for `{space-bar}`

And `"\n"` might work for `{enter-key}`

But how to specify `{up-arrow}` ?

NOTE: In my research, I'm finding some indication that the arrow-keys fall in the category of key-down, rather than key-press, so perhaps not possible to pipe arrow-keys as input ?

Thanks.

Comment: So, You want to navigate, and not print anything to screen! `echo` is used to display text!

Comment: Automating navigation around a curses interface will be very complicated (and likely prone to bugs), and you can't do it with the shell, you'll need something like expect to trick the command into thinking it's talking with a terminal. I strongly recommend trying to find a way to do this without having to trick a curses interface.

Comment: Ok, but independent of my ultimate use-case for piping non-printable characters to a shell command, it should still be possible to do so. How to supply the up-arrow key/character ?

Comment: Ctrl+V ↑ etc...

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use the code of [unicode characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters). Some examples:

- For space: `echo -e  "\u0020"`
- For newline (enter): `echo -e  "\u000A"`
- For up-arrow: `echo -e  "\u2191"`

See [List of Unicode characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) for all of them.

[image: echo unicode caracters]

Comment: It's better to use `printf` than getting into the habbit of using `echo` with options. E.g. `printf '\u2191'`. Note that unicode symbol 2191 has no relation to the up arrow key on the keyboard. In a terminal emulator, the up arrow key will produce an escape sequence, and the escape sequence will differ depending on what terminal emulator you use.

Comment: Will unicode 2191 piped as input to another command emulate the user pressing the up arrow key ( moving the cursor up the menu ) ?  Or is it an up-arrow glyph ?

Comment: Not sure why your referring back to this post. Your example for `\U2191` prints an up-arrow glyph - but I am interesting in emulating the user pressing the up-arrow.